# How to make msvc vectorize float addition?

Tags: c++, optimization, vectorization

I have this code:

```
constexpr size_t S = 4;
void add(std::array<float, S>& a, std::array<float, S> b)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < S; ++i)
        a[i] += b[i];
}
```

Both, clang and gcc, realize that instead of doing 4 single additions they can do one packed addition, using the `addps` instruction. E.g. clang generates this:

```
movups  xmm2, xmmword ptr [rdi]
movlhps xmm0, xmm1              # xmm0 = xmm0[0],xmm1[0]
addps   xmm0, xmm2
movups  xmmword ptr [rdi], xmm0
ret
```

As you can see on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/nsfRT1), gcc is a bit behind clang as it needs more moves. But that's fine. My problem is msvc which is way worse as you can see:

```
mov     eax, DWORD PTR _a$[esp-4]
movups  xmm2, XMMWORD PTR _b$[esp-4]
movss   xmm1, DWORD PTR [eax+4]
movaps  xmm0, xmm2
addss   xmm0, DWORD PTR [eax]
movss   DWORD PTR [eax], xmm0
movaps  xmm0, xmm2
shufps  xmm0, xmm2, 85                          ; 00000055H
addss   xmm1, xmm0
movaps  xmm0, xmm2
shufps  xmm0, xmm2, 170                   ; 000000aaH
shufps  xmm2, xmm2, 255                   ; 000000ffH
movss   DWORD PTR [eax+4], xmm1
movss   xmm1, DWORD PTR [eax+8]
addss   xmm1, xmm0
movss   xmm0, DWORD PTR [eax+12]
addss   xmm0, xmm2
movss   DWORD PTR [eax+8], xmm1
movss   DWORD PTR [eax+12], xmm0
ret     0
```

I tried different optimization levels, but `/O2` seems to be the best. I also tried manually unrolling the loop, but no change for msvc.

So, is there a way to make msvc do the same optimization, using one `addps` instead of four `addss`? Or is there maybe a good reason why msvc doesn't do it?

### **Edit**

By adding the `/Qvec-report:2` flag as suggested by Shawn in the comments (thanks!) I found out that msvc thinks the loop is to small to have any benefit from vectorizing it. Clang and gcc have different opinions, but OK.
And indeed, if I change `S` to `16`, msvc comes up with a vectorized version, even though it still provides a non vectorized branch (completely unnecessary in my opinion as `S` is known at compile time). In general, msvc's code looks like a mess compared to gcc and clang, see [here](https://godbolt.org/z/UyvLX4).

Comment: I can't think of any other way to force MSVC++ to do this except by using the explicit compiler intrinsic ([_mm_add_ps](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#text=add_ps&expand=133)). However, I am not very experienced in this field, so I could easily be wrong.

Comment: Compiling with [`/Qvec-report:2`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/qvec-report-auto-vectorizer-reporting-level?view=vs-2019) might give some helpful feedback.

Comment: Thanks for providing that command line option, it can be quite useful. Meanwhile, I believe I have diagnosed the problem. Therefore, I have now written an answer.

Comment: I will most probably get a lot of flak for this comment, but in my personal experience, it is quite unreliable to assume any compiler will vectorize your code. Seemingly small changes to the code might make the code stop being vectorized. If those functions are on a critical path of your computations, and you see a benefit from vectorization, use compiler specific intrinsics to force it.

Comment: @divinas: I agree with you. I have found the behavior of the Microsoft Visual C++ compiler to be quite inconsistent on when it vecorizes and when it doesn't. Other compilers, such as Clang, may be better, I haven't tested it.

Answer (score 2):

I have tested the code you posted in Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 and it works with me. When I call your function `add` with [aligned](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment) and non-[aliased](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_aliasing) parameters, your function `add` compiles to the `addps` instruction, not `addss`. Maybe you are using an older version of Visual Studio?

However, I was able to reproduce your problem by deliberately giving the function non-aligned or aliased parameters. In order to accomplish this, I replaced the function parameters with C-style array pointers (because I don't know how exactly `std::array` is implemented) and deliberately called the function with aliased pointers, by making the two arrays overlap. In that case, the generated code calls `addss` four times instead of `addps` once. Deliberately passing an unaligned pointer had the same effect.

This behavior also makes sense. For vectorization to be meaningful, the compiler must be sure that the arrays do not overlap and that they are properly aligned. I believe alignment is less of an issue with AVX than with SSE.

Of course, the compiler must be able to determine whether there is possible aliasing or alignment issues at compile-time, not at run-time. Therefore, maybe the problem is that you are calling the function in such a way that the compiler can't be sure at compile-time whether the paramaters are aliased and whether the parameters are aligned. Compilers are sometimes not very smart at determining these things. However, as you have pointed out in the comments section, since you are passing one parameter by value, the compiler should be able to determine that there is no danger of overlap. Therefore, my guess is that it is an alignment issue, as the compiler is unsure at compile-time how the contents of `std:array` is aligned. As I am unable to reproduce your problem using `std::array`, you may want to post your code on how you are calling the function.

You can also enforce vectorization by explicitly calling the corresponding compiler intrinsic [`_mm_add_ps`](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#text=add_ps&expand=133) for the instruction `addps`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This makes kind of sense, however, by its own rules the compiler should know that objects (`std::array` in this case) are aligned. And as I'm passing `b` by value it cannot overlap with `a`. Actually, I believe `std::array` objects cannot overlap in memory at all as opposed to pointers. Forcing them to overlap should be undefined behavior, and thus the compiler can assume that it never happens.

Comment: Yes, I agree that the compiler should be able to assume no overlap, since one of the parameters is passed by value. I will edit my answer accordingly. Since the compiler's behavior does not only depend on the contents of the function `add` but also how you are calling the function, I believe it would be best if you also posted the code which shows how you are calling the function. I am unable to reproduce your problem when using std::array. You did not answer my question on whether you are using an older version of the compiler than me.

Comment: Actually, for now I'm not using this code, I'm just reasoning about future options. Also, I haven't used Visual Studio at all, yet. I'm only experimenting inside of Compiler Explorer. However, according to this [mapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_C%2B%2B#32-bit_and_64-bit_versions) the latest available version on Compiler Explorer maps to Visual Studio 2019 Version 16.2

Comment: I believe you are right regarding the alignment. Have a look here: https://godbolt.org/z/teuOY8 If I pass both arrays by value and return the result, msvc is properly vectorizing it. Presumably, because it now can be sure that both arrays are aligned nicely. If you add that to your answer, I will accept it.

Comment: Thanks for your offer of accepting my answer. However, I'm afraid that the answer is not that simple. I was able to create a test program in which the compiler emitted an `addps` instruction, even when I forced the pointer to a C-style array of 4 floats to be unaligned, which was known to the compiler at compile-time. The behavior of the Visual C++ 2017 compiler seems inconsistent. Maybe I should upgrade to the new 2019 version. I will do some further testing.